# How to find the geometric mean of an array of ints using Math.pow

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to find the geometric mean of a small array of integers using Math.pow.
This is my first time using this syntax and I am not sure how to go about finishing my code.

I am currently going through last years exam papers and this is one of the questions.

Please forgive any errors in my code. I am still learning Java.

```
public class AverageOfArray {

public static void main(String []args){

    int [] data = new int[3];
    data[0] = 2;
    data[1] = 4;
    data[2] = 8;

    int y = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        sum = sum + data[i];
        y++;
    }

    Math.pow(sum, 1.0/data.length);
    System.out.println(sum);

}

}
```

Although the code runs fine without error, it is not giving me the output I require. The mean should be 4.

Here is the code after some edits:

```
public class AverageOfArray {

public static void main(String []args){

    int [] data = new int[3];
    data[0] = 2;
    data[1] = 4;
    data[2] = 8;


    double sum = 1.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        sum = sum * data[i];
    }

    double geoMean = Math.pow(sum, 1.0/data.length);
    System.out.println(geoMean);

}

}
```

However it is now returning 3.9999996? 
Am I looking at Math.abs here now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your [geometric mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) calculation is incorrect.  You must multiply all of the values together instead of adding them.  And your initial product must start with 1.0.

```
double product = 1.0;
```

and later...

```
product = product * data[i];
```

Additionally, store the result of `Math.pow` in a new variable -- a `double`, because that's what [`Math.pow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) returns.

```
double geoMean = Math.pow(product, 1.0 / data.length);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I was looking at that. I was researching on another website and there they were using addition!!
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, got it now. I keep forgetting about capturing my output. Thank you!!

Comment: Hmmm, my output is 3.9999999999999996.
Would I require Math.abs here to?

Comment: It looks like a few minor floating-point errors have shown up here.  It's likely that this is "close enough" for your purposes.  You can use `String.format` or a `DecimalFormat` to format your number with a given number of decimal places, e.g. `4.00` for 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 18):

From Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean#Relationship_with_arithmetic_mean_of_logarithms, it is common to implement a different (but equivalent) version of the geometric mean formula. That version uses logarithms to avoid over- and underflows. In Java, it may look look like this:

```
class GeometricMean {
    private GeometricMean() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] data = new long[]{2, 4, 8};
        double gm = geometricMean(data);
        System.out.println("Geometric mean of 2, 4 and 8: " + gm );
    }

    public static double geometricMean(long[] x) {
        int n = x.length;
        double GM_log = 0.0d;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (x[i] == 0L) {
                return 0.0d;
            }
            GM_log += Math.log(x[i]);
        }
        return Math.exp(GM_log / n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not covered Math.log or Math.exp yet!!
Many thanks though!! =]

Answer (score 4):

```
public static double geoMean(double[] arr) {

    if (arr.length == 0) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    double gm = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        gm *= arr[i];
    }
    gm = Math.pow(gm, 1.0 / (double) arr.length);

    return gm;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a couple of problems. First, you need to multiply values to get a geometric mean. Then, simply calling `Math.pow` will not change the value; it returns a new value that you must capture. For example:

```
sum = Math.pow(sum, 1.0 / data.length);
```

Comment: Ahh, yes I see. Thank you.
Then return it, or just print it.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala you can achieve it using a sum of logs (to prevent overflows) with:

```scala
def geomean(values: Double*): Double =
 math.exp((values.map(math.log(_)).sum) / values.length)
```